# "Request vscode/content failed unexpectedly without providing any details."

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to setup my **JavaScript Development Environment**. On transpiling with babel, VS-Code shows there is a problem

> Request vscode/content failed unexpectedly without providing any
>   details.

I have done some troubleshooting and found out that my `.babelsrc` file has an underline which needs to be removed. The Dev. Environment failed to transpile. See code below;

```
{            //there is a green underline here in my text editor
  "presets": [
    "latest"
  ]
}
```

I expected my Development environment to transpile my code to **ES5**, when I use **ES6** syntax.